# How Do I replace Specific Text in PHP

Tags: php

I have some data in the following format.

```
Orange - $3.00
Banana - $1.25
```

I would like to print this as only as follows:

```
Orange
Banana
```

I tried using following code in a loop but the data may have 0 in other places as well. So if I can find 0 only at the end for a specific line.

```
$pos=strpos($options, "0");
$options = substr($options, 0, $pos)."\n";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider using the PHP `explode()` function, which splits a string on the desired delimiter.  In this case, you'd want split each line on "-" I think, and just use the first element returned.  Or possibly split the entire tag by `\n` even before splitting on "-".

Comment: If you just want to print out the name of the fruit, why don't you look for the first space character in the string, instead of 0? If that's not what you're after, then you might need to explain what you're after in a little more depth.

Comment: You could probably try using a regex. Maybe "/([A-za-z0-9_\-]*) .*/"; this means "capture[series of letters,numbers,_,and -], then a space, then any other characters"

Comment: So if I look for the space as starting position for and how do I find the end position. I don't want to leave the end position without specifying number as I have other data as well at the end and I don't want to remove that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php
$input = 'Orange - $3.00';
list($fruit, $price) = explode('-', $input);
?>
```

Or if you want to proces all the input:

```
<?php
$input = 'Orange - $3.00
Banana - $1.25';
$fruitlist = array();
$sepLines = explode("\n", $input);
foreach($seplines as $line)
{
    list($fruit, $price) = explode(' - ', $line);
    $fruitlist[] = $fruit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to print only the name of the item and not the price?

```
$n=explode(" - ", "Banana - $1.25");
print $n[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = explode("-", $originalText);
$word = $string[0];
```

and thats it :)

Comment: Either use trim or choose a needle with spaces because you've an extra space at the end now...